# Can I search a vertex from a graph in using _key and dont know the collection name?

Tags: arangodb, arangodb-java

I have a problem when do a traversal for a graph.I think the ArangoDB java driver dont support to find a vertex in using _key.And this like the janusgraph "g.V().has('xxxx','yyy')".
Or can find a vertex from a graph in using _key?And how?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something so far. If yes, please include it. If you expected others to write the code for you, you're wrong here. Please see [ask]?

Comment: Thanks for you reply.I have resolved it by iterating the all collections.But I think that the java driver do graph traversal must know a startvertex，this not like janusgraph's `“g.V().has("xx")”`.The java driver only can get the all collections' name。How can I get All documents without knowing the collection name？

Comment: I realize that I'm late to the party...  I might be trying to do something similar...  Why are you trying to search for a vertex without knowing its collection?  Is this a case of traversing from an edge that can connect to vertices of different collections?  If so, might augmenting the edge to identify the collection of the ends be a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the SEARCH option is a solution:

- filter documents based on AQL Boolean expressions and functions
- **match documents located in different collections** backed by a fast index
- sort the result set based on how closely each document matched the search conditions

more info you can find here: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-search.html